# Using a derived field

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns

I have two tables. One is InvoiceHeader and the other is InvoiceDetails. I have a field in InvoiceHeader called total which I want to calculate all the costs associated with that InvoiceID from the InvoiceDetails table.

What is the easiest way I can go about doing this?

I am also working on Access. If you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the cost values are stored in a numeric field named `cost` in `InvoiceDetails`, and `InvoiceID` is also a numeric field in both tables ...

```sql
SELECT
    ih.*,
    DSum("cost", "InvoiceDetails", "InvoiceID = " & ih.InvoiceID)
        As total_cost
FROM InvoiceHeader AS ih;
```

Or you could use an aggregate query to compute the totals for each `InvoiceID` and join that to `InvoiceHeader`.

```sql
SELECT ih.*, sub.total_cost
FROM
    InvoiceHeader AS ih
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT InvoiceID, Sum(cost) AS total_cost
        FROM InvoiceDetails
        GROUP BY InvoiceID
    ) AS sub
    ON ih.InvoiceID = sub.InvoiceID;
```

If your tables are large enough to notice a speed difference between those 2 approaches, my guess is the second would be faster.  Whichever one you choose will greatly benefit from an index on `InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID`.

Comment: I have not yet created the database. I am just using some sample data and figuring out the queries I need. Will be a pretty minor database as it is just a college project. Personally I like the second solution you gave and that is what I will be going with. I have never seen it done like that before considering I am still pretty new at databases. Thanks for all your help.